# Setting visual studio 2022 win form controls default font

Tags: c#, winforms, fonts

The default font for C# win form control is `Microsoft Sans Serif, 8.25pt`.
This means that whenever a control is added to a form - this is the font setting the control gets.

I checked at VS menus: `Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Fonts and Colors`, but I didn't find setting for that.

Please advise

Comment: The default behavior for a Control is to inherit the Font from the Prent. If you set the Font of your Forms, its child Controls will inherit that Font. In .Net 6+, you can [set the Application's default Font](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/project-sdk/msbuild-props-desktop) in the Project's configuration file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VS settings are related to the IDE and not the project.

If you want to have "default" properties when you drag and drop a control, you just have to set the wanted property on the parent control, and the child will inherit from it.

So, basically, just set the font type and size on the form before dropping controls on it

Comment: _VS settings are related to the IDE and not the project_  - true. However there is something that sets the default size for the parent as well. Maybe it is not configurable. Your suggestion is nice and I will use it, yet it is a kind of "work around" in my eyes. If you are actually saying is that it is not possible at all, then it is what is it...

Comment: "However there is something that sets the default size for the parent as well", of course, they are set in the winforms items template. You can customize them if you want (they are located in the C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Windows Forms\1033" folder. But I can't garantie they persist during updates. You can also make your own templates. With templates you'll be able to set defaut to any properties you want. But I find it personally more tricky :)

Comment: OK. I would assume there will be "regular setting" for that.. apparently not )). sounds to me much for me. so I'll go with your initial suggestion ..) tx.